# How to give a unique constraint to a combination of columns in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, unique-constraint, composite-key

I have a Table with 4 Columns

Each Column will be A,B,C,D

Column A is the Primary key.
Column B has unique name constraint.

Now I want to remove the unique constraint for column B and give a unique constraint by combining the columns B, C and D. So the table will allow only one row with a particular value in columns B,C and D.

How can I give this type of a constraint?

I tried giving the composite unique key like :

```
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME ADD CONSTRAINT CONSTRAINT_NAME UNIQUE (COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C, COLUMN_D)
```

But it is checking whether any one of the constraint is present rather than checking for the combination of unique key constraint.

Comment: @Naveen I gave the constraint as you told.. but it seems that the constraint only checks for any one of the column names... I want it to be like a new row will not be allowed to enter all the three column values are already existing in the table.

Comment: hai @nigelthomas view this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109614/how-can-i-create-a-sql-unique-constraint-based-on-2-columns

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Create a unique key on those columns

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
  add CONSTRAINT YourTable_unique UNIQUE (B, C, D);
```

[Oracle/PLSQL: Unique Constraints](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/unique.php)

Comment: What's the naming convention? What if you have two unrelated unique values in a table? Then 'YourTable_unique' would be the same name.

Comment: @PhilipRego, you're right on your comment. The naming convention is up to the team, company, user to decide. It is just an example.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't see difference between OP's alter query and query in this answer. Am I missing something?

Comment: @whatever, the question was edited afterwards, in where they included the answer that i gave.

Answer (score 9):

> First of all you should drop an existing Constraint by using below ALTER Query.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
   DROP CONSTRAINT myUniqueConstraint;
```

> Now, you can create a [UNIQUE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-unique.htm) Constraint  by using the keyword UNIQUE with the combination of required Columns.

**For Example:**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
   ADD CONSTRAINT myUniqueConstraint UNIQUE(B, C, D);
```

[**Detailed explanation of UNIQUE Constraint here.**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-unique.htm)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109614/how-can-i-create-a-sql-unique-constraint-based-on-2-columns

Answer (score 2):

ALTER TABLE table_name DROP CONSTRAINT constraint_name;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX constraint_name ON table_name
(B,C,D)