# How can I enforce uniqueness on a combination of two columns in a database table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, constraints

I have a simple database with two tables :

`Catalog (`**`id_catalog`**`, name )`

`Product (`**`id_product`**`, name, quantity, id_catalog# )`

None of those fields can be empty, so I put a `NOT NULL` constraint everywhere.

But I need that two products couldn't have the same name if they are in the same catalog. How could I do that?

I mean

```
1, chocolat, 5, 1
2, chocolat, 7, 2
```

those are OK because they are in two different catalogs, but :

```
1, chocolat, 5, 1
2, chocolat, 7, 1
```

should not be allowed, because I shouldn't accept chocolat twice in the same catalog.

Comment: Oracle supports [multi-column unique constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343516/how-to-give-a-unique-constraint-to-a-combination-of-columns-in-oracle) if that's what you need?

Comment: This is typically solved bey either creating a constraint (unique) or by creating a unique index. I personally think that the first method is better because more descriptive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a [unique index](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CREATE-INDEX.html#GUID-1F89BBC0-825F-4215-AF71-7588E31D8BFE) to avoid inserting more than one row with the same couple (`name, id_catalog#`).

Create the table:

```
SQL> create table Product(id_product number, name varchar2(10), quantity number, id_catalog# number);

Table created.
```

Add an index    :

```
SQL> create unique index idx1 on Product (name, id_catalog#);

Index created.
```

This will work:

```
SQL> insert into Product (id_product, name, quantity, id_catalog#) values (1, 'chocolat', 5, 1);

1 row created.
```

This will not work:

```
SQL> insert into Product (id_product, name, quantity, id_catalog#) values (2, 'chocolat', 7, 1);
insert into Product (id_product, name, quantity, id_catalog#) values (2, 'chocolat', 7, 1)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (ALEK.IDX1) violated
```

But this will, due to different `id_catalog#`

```
SQL> insert into Product (id_product, name, quantity, id_catalog#) values (2, 'chocolat', 7, 2);

1 row created.

SQL>
```