# making two combinations of two columns unique using one common column name

Tags: mysql, sql, unique-constraint

i just wanted to quickly as if anybody thought the following would cause problems:

i have a table with quite a few columns, three being 'fullname', 'groupid' and 'pp_num'.

I want to make the following two combinations unique:

fullname + groupid

fullname + pp_num

this would make it so no more than one row has either combination. would this cause any problems for me at all, besides the fact that it imposes a restriction?

any heads up is much appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you rigth. You wanna create a new column either with this combination `fullname + groupid` or the other one?

Comment: @JorgeCampos no all columns are in one table, just want to make both of the above combinations unique in the table

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `your_index_name` ON `table_name` (`fullname`, `groupid`);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `your_index_name` ON `table_name` (`fullname`, `pp_num`);
```

Or edit your CREATE statements to include:

```
UNIQUE INDEX indexname (col1,col2)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

Answer (score 0):

Add unique constraint to combination of two columns is what you are trying to do the post here answers your query.

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109614/how-can-i-create-a-sql-unique-constraint-based-on-2-columns)

Besides an example from there exactly as per your requirements.

```
    CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX index_name ON TABLE (col1,col2)
                                 or
    CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX index_name ON TABLE (col1,col2)
```

Comment: The other solution is so simple. you can split the constraint up, so there's one for fullname and groupid, and for fullname and pp_num.

Comment: what is the purpose of nonclustered?

Comment: I know how to create the query, im just asking if it will cause problems in querying later on in having the above two constraints together

Comment: With a non clustered index there is a second list that has pointers to the physical rows. You can have many non clustered indexes, although each new index will increase the time it takes to write new records. It should not create any problems while querying later is what i strongly feel.